# Install serilog and configure in an asp .net 4.7.1 webapi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, serilog

I can not find any resources for installing Serilog in an ASP.Net 4.7.1 WebApi project.  Can someone help me out?  There are a ton of .Net Core resources but that does not help.

Answer (score 20):

Install required NuGet packeges, open the `Package Manager Console` and type

```
Install-Package Serilog
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File
```

Create new static class with name `logger` that will have Serilog configuration

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static readonly ILogger _errorLogger;

    static Logger()
    {
        _errorLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logs/log-.txt"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public static void LogError(string error)
    {
        _errorLogger.Error(error);
    }
}
```

Use `logger` class when you want to log error as below

```
Logger.LogError("Test error log!");
```

Comment: I got too caught up in the tutorials and how they setup serilog.  This is the right answer for my project.  I'm using an exception filter and this works perfectly.

Comment: agree, keep it simple

Comment: I think this is not needed anymore.  Serilog has a "Log" static class, with a Logger property to initialize it.  So you can initialize it in the Startup class and just use it everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways one can configure `Serilog` in `.net framework 4.7.2`:

1. By using code only
2. By using app.config

Following nuget packages needed to be installed:

```
    Install-Package Serilog
    Install-Package Serilog.Settings.AppSettings
    Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File
```

**1st Way (By Using code only):**

Make a `static` `serilogclass`:

```
public static class SerilogClass
    {
        public static readonly Serilog.ILogger _log;
        static SerilogClass()
        {
            _log = new LoggerConfiguration().
                    MinimumLevel.Debug().                    
                    WriteTo.File(@Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData") + "\\Logs\\Logs1.log").
                    CreateLogger();
        }

    }
```

Note: `@Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData")` will save logfile into `appdata` folder

Initialize and Use the `SerilogClass` in `program.cs`

```
class Program
    {       
        static readonly Serilog.ILogger log = SerilogClass._log;
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
             log.Debug("This is serialog Example");
             log.Debug("This is serialog Example2");
        }
            
    }
```

**2nd Way(By using app.config):**

Make a `static` `serilogclass`:

```
public static class SerilogClass
    {       
        public static readonly Serilog.ILogger _log;        
        static SerilogClass()
        {
            _log = new LoggerConfiguration().
                    ReadFrom.AppSettings().
                    CreateLogger();
        }

    }
```

Initialize and Use the `SerilogClass` in `program.cs`

```
 class Program
        {       
            static readonly Serilog.ILogger log = SerilogClass._log;
            
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {            
                 log.Debug("This is serialog Example using app.config");
                 log.Debug("This is serialog Example2 using app.config");
            }
                
        }
```

We need too add `<appSettings></appSettings>` section to define all settings which we were doing via code in 1st way

`App.config`:

```
<configuration> 
    <configSections></configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug"/>
        <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />     
        <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="C:\Logs\LogSerilog.txt" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:File.shared" value="true" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollOnFileSizeLimit" value="true" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:File.fileSizeLimitBytes" value="2000" />
    </appSettings>
    <startup></startup>
    <runtime></runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i simply made a static serilog class and initialized it in main class to use it (for my console application .net framework 4.7.2):

```
 public static class SerilogClass
    {
        public static readonly Serilog.ILogger _log;
        static SerilogClass() 
        {
        _log= new LoggerConfiguration().
                MinimumLevel.Debug().
                WriteTo.File(@"D:\MyPoject\Logs.log").
                CreateLogger();
        }
                 
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
 class Program
    {
        static readonly Serilog.ILogger log3 = SerilogClass._log;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            log3.Debug("This is serialog Example");
        }
}
```