# Asp.Net Web Api Logging

Tags: asp.net-web-api, serilog

I want to setup logging on my asp.net web api (**Not** Asp.Net Core), and want to make sure that I follow best practices (as close as possible). I am using SeriLog in my services, and would like to use this product for my Web Api as well. I am not sure of the best way to setup logging in Web API, and I would like to set it up such that depending on the context (my api serves multiple apps) I would like to be able to log to a separate Microsoft Sql Server. Can somebody please provide some direction on how to get started at this task, potential pitfalls, or a link to an article that I have yet to find on how to set this up in Asp.Net?

Comment: @PeterBons Sorry for the confusion, but I'm not using .net core.

Comment: Hi, I have added a rather detailed version of the config we have been using for our Web APIs in my previous job from 2015-ish to 2018 . It might be useful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55365917/474763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a centralized logger project and add serilog packages to this project only, and reference this project where you need to use serilog (your services).

And configure serilog using [Serilog.Settings.AppSettings](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings) package so each service project will read its own configuration (Ex: separate Microsoft SQL Server) from `<appSettings>` section in service `web.config` useing the `ReadFrom.AppSettings()` extension method on your `LoggerConfiguration`

Sample Logger Class

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static readonly ILogger _dbLogger;

    static Logger()
    {
        _dbLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public static void Log(string error)
    {
        _dbLogger.Error(error);
    }
}
```

Sample `appSettings` configuration

```
<add key="serilog:using:MSSqlServer" value="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString" value="Server=..."/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.tableName" value="Logs"/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.autoCreateSqlTable" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library from Serilog ([MSSQL-Server](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver))